# GCC or make flag to forbid particular standard library functions

Tags: c, gcc, qmake

I'm working on a multithreaded project which suffered from a number of bugs due to use of the library function "strtok()" which is not thread-safe.

I'd love to find a way to forbid use of this function (and perhaps others) by defining something in the project file (Qt Creator / qmake) (e.g. redefining the symbol), to keep new developers or seasoned bugmakers from introducing it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well there is [gcc poison](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/cpp/Pragmas.html)

Comment: As you have to replace it anyway, why not search all files for its usage?

Comment: @Olaf searching for and fixing current uses doesn't help when someone later adds code that calls strtok. The OP could create his own strtok that causes an abort if called - newly added calls to strtok will then be found during your unit testing.

Comment: @FredK: Agreed. The uint-test should the automatically send the fire-mail to the person who violated the coding standard.... But who dares to fire the boss?

Comment: You can scan your executables for the `strtok` symbol after you build them, with use of an object file analysis tool such as `nm`.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, that is exactly the issue - easy to fix now, hard to enforce in future.

Comment: It is not ideal but if have one place you can add `#pragma GCC poison strtok` then it will make this an error.

Comment: I like "seasoned bugmakers", or what ed yourdon called "Net negative producers"

Answer (score 1):

this is what the GCC manual says about elimination of the use of certain library functions:

```
#pragma GCC poison
Sometimes, there is an identifier that you want to remove completely
from your program, and make sure that it never creeps back in. 
To enforce this, you can poison the identifier with this pragma. 
#pragma GCC poison is followed by a list of identifiers to poison. 
If any of those identifiers appears anywhere in the source after the directive, 
it is a hard error. For example,

          #pragma GCC poison printf sprintf fprintf
          sprintf(some_string, "hello");


will produce an error.

If a poisoned identifier appears 
as part of the expansion of a macro which was defined 
before the identifier was poisoned, it will not cause an error. 
This lets you poison an identifier 
without worrying about system headers defining macros that use it.

For example,

          #define strrchr rindex
          #pragma GCC poison rindex
          strrchr(some_string, 'h');


will not produce an error.
```

Comment: The biggest problem with the usage of this pragma is inforcing that it is included in every source file, after the #include statements.

Comment: Which is why I did not make my comment and answer since it is not ideal and the OP did not say it was an acceptable solution. Although I think this is best the OP will get.